# Running multiline command of *.cmd file from C# Code

Tags: c#, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I have a file in E drive E:\1\2\Abc.cmd and following line written in this file

```
@:again
@..\xyz.exe  param1 param2
@goto again
```

xyz.exe path is E:\1\xyz.exe

If I double click on abc.cmd then it is working fine but it is throwing exception when running form C# code. Saying  `“..\xyz.exe is not recognized as internal or external commad”`.

I have written following code

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"E:\1\2\Abc.cmd";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Comment: You most often see this error when you're not calling the command from the directory you think you're calling it from. Put an `echo %cd%` command before calling xyz.exe and see where you actually are. It's generally also a good idea to use the full path when calling an external program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "E:\\1\\2\\Abc.cmd";
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = "E:\\1\\2\\";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```